# Split score into votes

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign

On SO, if you click on a question or answer's score, you can see the number of up and down votes forming that score. I love this feature, but superuser.com doesn't appear to have it. Why not?

Answer (score 9):

Because you don't have 1000 reputation yet.

See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8211/hidden-features-of-stack-overflow/31491#31491)

Comment: Ah, never realized this was a perk. Thanks!